# how to send parameters to smart contract while deploying using metamask

Tags: solidity, metamask

I am trying to deploy a smart contract using BrowserSolc and Metamask. and deployed successfully when the contract doesn't have constructor parameters but now I am trying to deploy with the constructor parameter but unable to do it.

How to add a parameter to the `send_ethTransaction` method

```
const source = "pragma solidity 0.4.24;contract SujiToken { string public name = 'Suji';    string public symbol = 'SUJI';  string public standard = 'Suji Token v1.0'; uint256 public totalSupply; event Transfer(     address indexed _from,      address indexed _to,        uint256 _value      );  event Approval(     address indexed _owner,     address indexed _spender,       uint256 _value      );  mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;   mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;   constructor(uint256 _amount) public{ require(_amount >0,'amount should be greater than zero');      totalSupply = _amount;      balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;    }   function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public payable returns (bool success){       require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);       balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;        balanceOf[_to] += _value;       emit Transfer(msg.sender,_to,_value);       return true;    }   function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){       allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;       emit Approval(msg.sender,_spender,_value);      return true;    }   function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {      require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;     balanceOf[_to] += _value;       allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;     emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);      return true;    }}"
BrowserSolc.loadVersion("soljson-v0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.js", async(compiler) => {
    // console.log(compiler);
    optimize = 1;
    var result = compiler.compile(source,optimize);
    console.log(result);
    var byteCode = result.contracts[':SujiToken'].bytecode;
    // console.log(byteCode);
    if(window.ethereum){
        var web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        await ethereum.enable();
        const params = {
            "type" : "ERC20",
            "from": ethereum.selectedAddress,
            "gasPrice": "750000", // 10000000000000
            "data": "0x"+byteCode
        };
        ethereum.sendAsync({
            method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
            params: [params],
            from: ethereum.selectedAddress, // Provide the user's account to use.
        }, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            if(result){
                $('input[contract_hash]').val(result.result);
                //$('form').submit();
            }
        })
        // ethereum.send
        // console.log(window.web3);
    }else{
        console.log("Non ethereum browser has been detected");
    }
});
```

this is the code i am trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

> You can pass parameters of the constructor during deployment like
>   this:

```
// Instantiate from an existing address:
var myContractInstance = MyContract.at(myContractAddress);
// Or deploy a new contract:
// Deploy the contract asynchronous from Solidity file:
...
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require('solc')
let source = fs.readFileSync('nameContract.sol', 'utf8');
let compiledContract = solc.compile(source, 1);
let abi = compiledContract.contracts['nameContract'].interface;
let bytecode = compiledContract.contracts['nameContract'].bytecode;
let gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: bytecode});
let MyContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));
var myContractReturned = MyContract.new(param1, param2, {
  from:mySenderAddress,
  data:bytecode,
  gas:gasEstimate}, function(err, myContract){
   if(!err) {
      // NOTE: The callback will fire twice!
      // Once the contract has the transactionHash property set and once its deployed on an address.
       // e.g. check tx hash on the first call (transaction send)
      if(!myContract.address) {
          console.log(myContract.transactionHash) // The hash of the transaction, which deploys the contract

      // check address on the second call (contract deployed)
      } else {
          console.log(myContract.address) // the contract address
      }
       // Note that the returned "myContractReturned" === "myContract",
      // so the returned "myContractReturned" object will also get the address set.
   }
 });
// Deploy contract syncronous: The address will be added as soon as the contract is mined.
// Additionally you can watch the transaction by using the "transactionHash" property
var myContractInstance = MyContract.new(param1, param2, {data: bytecode, gas: 300000, from: mySenderAddress});
myContractInstance.transactionHash // The hash of the transaction, which created the contract
myContractInstance.address // undefined at start, but will be auto-filled later
```

> For more information about this, you can read this [document](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract).